# How to plug into Laravel

Tags: laravel, hook

I can develop Laravel packages and can made custom blade, migration, model, controller, route from a package. But my question is specifically on how can I plug onto a default CRUD that was already built, from a package to modify that.

I started my PHP career from CMS like WordPress, Drupal, and then CakePHP, Laravel. Starting with procedural coding, OOP was a learning curve and is still a learning curve for mine. But scouring different platform made me understand that, the same thing can be achieved in different ways.

With WordPress plugin development experience, it's easy to extend functionality using action and filter hooks. With a core functionality like:

```
Fetch form data (3 fields)
     hook here <---
Load form data (3 fields)
Submit form data (3 fields)
     hook here <---
Save form data (3 fields)
```

can be easily modified from a plugin like:

```
Fetch form data (3 fields)
     action hook <--- (hooked - added 2 fields)
Load form data (5 fields)
Submit form data (5 fields)
     filter hook <--- (hooked - added data of 2 additional fields)
Save form data (5 fields)
```

But when in Laravel, I want to achieve a similar feature being in Laravel scope, **how can I?**

I understand the use of `@yield('my_hook')` is similar to the action hook in WordPress. But found that, if I hook multiple onto `@yield` it's getting overridden.

I found several packages like [eventy](https://github.com/tormjens/eventy) with a similar approach of action and filter hook of WordPress, but I'm actually asking for a Laravel approach to the issue.

I came across to the [Laravel Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events), is that the solution to hook like an action hook in WordPress? And the filter hook, I think we can extend a model to modify its behavior. But I'm afraid, these are all the imagination, and might not be the reality. I don't have any idea on that.

Can I get some enlightenment onto this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both WordPress and Laravel are frameworks on a whole different level, so comparison might be difficult.

In Laravel you have tools to control the output (html page). `@yield` is an example, when you are using Blade templates.

Furthermore there are methods to hook on certain events within the execution of the framework (Laravel Events).

In Laravel you are working in a Model-View-Control setting meaning that you can/should:

- Make a Model of every data-entity you are using and give it the responsibility to do it's own work. See also https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events for hooks
- Make Controller methods for every action you want to execute from the front-end. It is a good practice to keep these methods as short as possible. e.g. max 10 lines.
- Make sophisticated templates using the Blade Template engine

Hope this will help.